# Detecting if user has (a) finger(s) in the area of a UIScrollView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to track if the user has a finger (or fingers) in the area of a UIScrollView. I overrode UIScrollView's `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to track the number of touches that are "down" and "up".

This seems to work perfectly otherwise, but when the screen is panned, it seems that UIScrollView doesn't call these methods.

Which is the correct way to detect if the user is touching UIScrollView or not?

Answer (score 0):

These properties of `UIScrollView` may be the best choice instead of messing with the

`- (void)touchesBegan` `- (void)touchesCancelled` `- (void)touchesEnded` methods

```
if (yourScrollView.isTracking || yourScrollView.isZooming || yourScrollView.isDragging)
{
    // User interacting
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd need to have an event when the touch setup is changed.

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro Use the delegate callbacks and check for these properties inside them.